# Updating a field of a tablet, after a comparation of value of another table and search if value is present inside a field of a table Hard Job

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have 2 table in SQL ,
i need to check if in table payment on field description is contain the code 
present on table shipping, if yes, write 1 on filed mark only if code is present on field drscription, for example in this case only on line 3 mark should become 1

```
payment                                         shipping

id  description      amount             number      code      mark
1    payment dog       10                 1          sky       0
2    payment cat       20                 2          bed       0
3    payment frog      30                 3          dog       1




 $sqlupdate= "UPDATE shipping SET shipping.mark = '1' IN ( SELECT description FROM payment WHERE description LIKE '%$code%' )";

$sql = "SELECT number, code, mark FROM shipping WHERE mark = '0'";
$conn->query($sql);
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$code= $row['code'];
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlupdate)) {
 echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
 echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

this it doesn't return me error, but it doesn't update the database,

i asl tryied using other methods,

but i never reach my goal

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one query.  If you want to just update values to "1", then use:

```
UPDATE shipping s JOIN
       descriptions d
       ON d.description LIKE CONCAT('%', s.code);
    SET s.mark = 1 ;
```

If you want to update all values (both "1"s and "0"s), then:

```
UPDATE shipping s
   SET mark = EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM descriptions d
                      WHERE d.description LIKE CONCAT('%', s.code)
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below by using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` for getting the code from description column then use wherer condition

```
       UPDATE shipping 
        SET shipping.mark = '1' 
        where shipping.code IN 
( SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(description,' ',-1) FROM payment WHERE description LIKE '%$code%' )
```